# For each sub-folder in directory, delete files with a specific extension, only if a file with same filename + different specified extension exists

Tags: bash, macos, sh, batch-processing, file-management

I have a large collection of music that I've built over the space of 15 years as a DJ.

A few years back I decided to buy/download music primarily in FLAC format. I've since run into problems running with this format -- many of the clubs/festivals where I play my sets will supply non-industry standard Pioneer CDJ decks that don't support FLAC files.

I have now converted (and painstakingly rebuilt) my entire digital library to a universal CDJ format, AIFF. Each converted AIFF file was placed in the same folder location as the original FLAC files. I am now left with the original FLAC files which I no longer want.

I'm wanting to:

Delete files with a .flac extension that exists in a folder, for each folder within a parent directory, only if an .aif/aiff/aifc file exists with a matching filename. Any .flac files without a corresponding .aiff, show in a (Finder?) list for conversion.

```
- MUSIC
    - Artist A
       + track1.flac [*delete]
       + track1.aiff
    - Artist B
       + track2.flac [*delete]
       + track2.aiff
    - Artist C
       + track3.flac [*add to finder list for conversion?]
```

*my music library folder is

I'm not too sure how to go about this... my coding/scripting level is pretty basic.

I'm on a Mac machine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is aiff better then flac?

Comment: Same-same, really. There's no audible difference between flac and aiff - both are lossless audio codecs/formats, and both produce identical PCM audio streams. Flac compresses PCM audio data into a zip-like container which is decompressed in its original form upon playback, whereas aiff format stores the original uncompressed PCM audio stream.

I guess aiff would be preferable for Apple users... and DJs. Flac isn't natively supported on macOS, iOS etc. Flac for those who want smaller file size ~30%

Comment: I'd recommend making sure you have a good backup first -- automated mass file deletions can do a lot of damage if anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Delete files with a .flac extension that exists in a folder, for each folder within a parent directory, only if an .aif/aiff/aifc file exists with a matching filename. Any .flac files without a corresponding .aiff, show in a (Finder?) list for conversion.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s extglob
to_convert=()
for file in **/*.flac; do
    flac=$file
    aiff="${file%.flac}.aiff"
    if [[ -e "$aiff" ]]; then
       rm -i "$aiff"
    else
        toconvert+=("$flac")
    fi
done
echo "You still have to convert:"
printf "  %s\n" "${toconvert[@]}"
```

To research: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide , bash arrays, looping over files in shel, extended glob `extglob` in bash, parameter expansion.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will have a good read through the documentation before I give it a shot.. might as well learn something new. Cheers for getting me started